# Best practice to handle refresh AAD token when using Azure Resource Management API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-hdinsight, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-.net

I'm following this guidance https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-create-linux-clusters-dotnet-sdk/ to use ARM based HDInsight client to create clusters.

The logic is like this:

```
var authToken = authContext.AcquireToken(params...);
var hdiClient = new HDInsightManagementClient(authToken);
hdiClient.Clusters.Create(params...);
//use hdiClient to do other things, like create clusters ...
```

As AAD token only has 1 hour expiration time. It's really easy to hit when I use the hdiClient to create clusters and query the status. In this case I need to wrap all the methods in hdiClient I used to handle the renew token things.

Are there any best practices to handle this? Or is there an token expiration event exposed to user to handle it? Although my case a HDInsight scenario, I think all Azure Resource Manager Client should have this similar issue when using AAD...

Answer (score 2):

It’s a recommended best practice to refresh the access token before each call. This is a workaround to writing code that checks the access token expiration date and time and refreshes the token when it’s about to expire.

To refresh the access token, which is usually cached, you simply call the `AcquireToken` method again using the same context.

```
AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientId, new Uri(redirectUrl));
```

Comment: In real scenario, there are also many query API used to get the cluster status when doing CRUD operations with the client. If for each call, I need t o do a refresh. That will be the solution I mentioned, wrap all the methods in hdiClient I used to handle the renew token things...